# Angular Material Date Picker Filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have formatted my angular material date picker like below:

```
$mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function(date) {
        return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    };
```

But when I want to use date picker as filter, it's not working:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="search.date""></md-datepicker>
```

with `<input ng-model="search.date">` date filter working.

How could I make angular material date picker working with filter?

Edit :
 datepicker output is : `Tue Jun 21 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)`, but I want `2016-06-21`

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 double quotes in there.

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="search.date""></md-datepicker>
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/webservconsultant/pen/zBxJLZ) is working code.

```
$mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function(date) {
        return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    };
})
```